# invoking scheduleJob from Jmx

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to kick off a quartz job from jmx. I have the jmx connection established and I can see the quartz/QuartzScheduler/Spring/SchedulerFactory MBean on visualvm.

There is a method called "scheduleJob" that takes four parameters p1, p2, p3, p4 and return a date.

I'm not sure what those parameters should be? Can I kick off a job from this method? and what should be my parameters?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the quartz javadoc, you can find the list of all the methods exposed through the MBean.

http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/core/jmx/QuartzSchedulerMBean.html

HIH

Comment: Thanks for yuor answer, but I was looking for usage examples, not javadoc. I solved the problem, exporting my MBeans and not using Quartz scheduler's MBean.